# ERROR pj_get_spheroid_defn EXTENSION POSTGIS2_96 POSTGRES-9.6

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.3

I recently had this error, and surely other people also are going to have when they update the POSTGIS and POSTGRESQL, so I want to share the solution.

OS: CENTOS 6 (x86_64)

Installed: postgresql-9.6
from [this repository](https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm)

```
yum install postgresql96-server postgresql96
```

installer: postgis2_96

```
yum install postgis2_96
```

problem/error when start to enable POSTGIS using psql or pgAdminIII :

```
psql (9.6.3)    
postgres=# \connect SANTANDER
    You are now connected to database "SANTANDER" as user "postgres".
    SANTANDER=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
    ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.6/lib/postgis-2.3.so": /usr/pgsql-9.6/lib/postgis-2.3.so: undefined symbol: pj_get_spheroid_defn
```

I checked the PROJ version:

```
$ yum list installed | grep proj 
proj.x86_64        4.7.0-1.el6                           @epel
```

the problem is solved upgrading the PROJ

```
$ yum upgrade proj
Updated:
  proj.x86_64 0:4.8.0-2.rhel6
```

Comment: Please post the **solution**  in a self-answer to your question in the **Answers** section below.